# how to add a new item into an object

Tags: javascript, object

i am learning about objects and i have a nested object which is named `owners` inside `dog`, how can i add a new owner ?

```
const dog = {
       owners: {
              owner1: {
                     id: "1",
                     name: "John Doe",
              },
              owner2: {
                     id: "2",
                     name: "Jane Doe",
              }
       },
};
```

Comment: Exactly that. You could use square brackets (typically reserved for dynamic property referencing), or it would be more conventional to use dot syntax - `dog.owners.owner3 = { ... };`. You may also want to consider making the `owners` property an array of objects. `dog.owners = [{ ... }, { ... }, { ... }];`

Comment: @fubar Thank you so much! I'm really struggling with working with objects. Once they get complicated I get totally lost

Comment: If your object only contains properties named in the form xxxxxxxSequenceNumber then you should probably be using an array and not an object.

Comment: "I think I would do something like…" — Have you tried it? Didn't it work? What exactly is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

```
dog.owners.owner3 = {
  {
    id: "2",
    name: "Jane Doe",
  }
};
```

The JavaScript parser evaluates this from left to right. dog points to the owners object and sets a new property called owner3 that points to the new object.

You can also pass a string value inside brackets if you don't know what the property names will be.

```
const newOwner = "owner3";
dog.owners[newOwner] = {};
```

Answer (score -1):

Recommended way is using `spread operator`,

```js
const dog = {
       owners: {
              owner1: {
                     id: "1",
                     name: "John Doe",
              },
              owner2: {
                     id: "2",
                     name: "Jane Doe",
              }
       },
};

  // 1 way javascript dyanamic way
  // dog.owners["owner3"] = {id: 3, name: 'Bob Smith'};

  // 2 way (using spread opertor)
  dog.owners = {...dog.owners, owner3:{id: 3, name: 'Bob Smith'}}
  
  // 3 way using object.assign  
  //dog.owners = Object.assign({}, dog.owners, {owner3:{id: 3, name: 'Bob Smith'}})



console.log(dog.owners)
```

Comment: The question is asking how to add the property to an object. This creates a new object. Any existing references to the old object will be unchanged.

Comment: He probably just wants to know how to add a new property to existing object and my answer shows it using two ways...